# How to GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl for Document Library/Folder name containing special characters?

Tags: document-library, csom, url, special-characters, relative-path

Suppose I have a document library or, a folder inside a document library with some special character e.g. te$t. I want to do GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl to upload some file to that folder. But it fails because the url removes these special characters. What is the right way to handle this in Client Object Model?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried URL encoding..

**$ = %24**

Answer (score 0):

Use URL encoding for all parameters before REST call. So te$t will become te%24t which is accepted,